# Error 'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: django, websocket

I already install docker with this command in django:

> pip install docker

But when i try to run docker command, it give me error -- it is not recognize.. what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the description on pypi repo states:
https://pypi.org/project/docker/

> A Python library for the Docker Engine API. It lets you do anything the docker command does, but from within Python apps – run containers, manage containers, manage Swarms, etc.

This is only an API wrapper for docker and not the docker itself. To install docker follow the official Documentation.

https://docs.docker.com/install/

Comment: Thanks.. now i got it